# Finding $f(x)$ in a Fourier Integral

Tags: calculus, functions, periodic-functions

I'm having trouble trying to find that function $f(x)$ or trying to find that it doesn't exist.

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)\sin(\alpha x)dx=
\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
\alpha & \alpha \in (0, 2\pi) \\
e^{-(\alpha - 2\pi)} & \alpha \in (2\pi, \infty)
\end{array}
\right.$$

I know that I am supposed to analyse that comparing to a Fourier Integral but I am stuck trying to analyse $\alpha $ and its values when <0,=0,>0.. Still, I don't have much idea of what to do in this question..

edit: we can assume that the function is odd

Sorry for the latex and thank you in advance!

Comment: I suggested an edit to make it look better formatting-wise

Comment: No problem I hope it gets some attention so you can get an answer, also you can make the sine look better by using \sin{\alpha x}

Comment: Hahah ye, I'm still stuck in this one

Comment: Do you know if $f(x)$ is even or odd or any other side information?

Comment: we can assume that is odd

Comment: @RafaelVignoli Please add it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given equation is the [Sine Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_and_cosine_transforms) of $f(x)$.

> $$F_s(\omega)=2\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\sin(2\pi\omega x) dx$$

So with change of variable $\alpha=2\pi\omega,$
$$F_s(\omega)=2\int_0^\infty f(x)\sin(2\pi\omega x)dx=
\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
4\pi\omega & \omega \in (0, 1) \\
2e^{-2\pi(\omega - 1)} & \omega \in (1, \infty)
\end{array}
\right.$$

The inverse transform is

> $$f(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}F_s(\omega)\sin(2\pi\omega x) d\omega$$

Thus

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\int_{0}^{1}4\pi\omega\sin(2\pi\omega x) d\omega+\int_{1}^{\infty}2e^{-2\pi(\omega - 1)}\sin(2\pi\omega x) d\omega\\
&=\frac{\sin(2\pi x)-2\pi x\cos(2\pi x)}{\pi x^2}+\frac{x\cos(2\pi x)+\sin(2\pi x)}{\pi(1+x^2)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: That's great, thank u!

Comment: Notice that the cosine transform is zero since the function is odd. Otherwise we needed the cosine transform as well, in the inverse transform.